# Why does this code overwrite my object when i want it to add to the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have the following code. It all works exactly as i wish except for one thing. When a user enters another item_name (leaving room_name as is) it wipes the original item_name. What I require is for it to add another item into the object

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="room_name" id="room_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Room name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="item_name" id="item_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Item name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="item_description" id="item_description" class="form-control" placeholder="Item description">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="inventory" id="inventory" class="form-control" placeholder="DEBUG">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a id="submitinv" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Submit</a>
                </div>
                <table id="list" class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ROOM NAME</th>
                        <th>ITEM NAME</th>
                        <th>ITEM DESCRIPTION</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
             </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
roominventory = {};
obj = {};
$('#submitinv').click(function(){
    room_name = $('#room_name').val();
    item_name = $('#item_name').val();
    item_description = $('#item_description').val();
    obj[item_name] = item_description;
    roominventory[room_name] = obj;
    $('#inventory').val(JSON.stringify(roominventory));
    obj = {};
    $('#list').append('<tr><td>' + room_name + '</td><td>' + item_name + '</td><td>' + item_description + '</td></tr>');
});

</script>
```

Comment: You are overwriting the object by calling obj = {};

Comment: but if i do not do that then when a user creates a new room_name it carries over the info from the original room_name

Comment: Then use `var room_name`. as written you have multiple global variables.

Comment: or instead of storing obj create a deep copy of it and then destroy-initialize obj.

Comment: use `var obj = {}` at the start of the click function, and remove the global version from outside the click. This way a new obj is created on each click and added to the roominventory. And like Shilly said, you should be using `var` for each of your variables. Global variables arent a good idea

Comment: Why the downvotes...?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u05Lhabn/

Comment: I have edited the code as described and it still overwrites. I have even used the code from craicerjacks fiddle and it behaves the same

Comment: Perhaps I am not being clear enough. What I want to happen is roominventory[room_name] = obj; to add another item into roominventory[room_name]  and not to replace roominventory[room_name] with the current obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we tell our worker:

```
roominventory[room_name] = obj
```

What we are saying is:

```
Find the key on the object roominventory that is equivalent to the
value room_name. I now want you to assign the value of obj to that key.
```

It sounds like that is not what you are wanting to tell your worker. What it sounds like you are wanting to tell your worker is:

```
Find the key on the object roominventory that is equivalent to the
value room_name. Now add the object to that value.
```

There are a few ways to do this, the easiest being making each key in the `roominventory` object be an array doing something like this:

```
// First we check if we have messed with this key before
if(roominventory[room_name] !== undefined){
  // if we have, let's just push our new object onto the list
  roominventory[room_name].push(obj)
}else{
  // if we haven't, let's create a list of a single item to add to later
  roominventory[room_name] = [obj]
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much Tim. That is exactly what I want and your description is PERFECT. This helps me in so many ways understand what is happening.

Thanks again,

Clint

Comment: Glad I could help Clint and glad that you got your problem solved! I have to ask myself all the time 'What am I actually telling my worker and what does my worker know when I tell them?' I find it helps debug and to come up with reusable solutions!